# WPF: Tooltip Placement behaves different on touchscreen

Tags: wpf, touch, tooltip

I have a ToggleButton with a tooltip:

```
            <ToggleButton Height="32" Width="32">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{someImage} />
                <ToggleButton.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Placement="Left" HorizontalOffset="-5">
                        <TextBlock Text="Search"/>
                    </ToolTip>
                </ToggleButton.ToolTip>
            </ToggleButton>
```

On my PC (regular screens, Windows 8.1) the tooltip is showing to the left of my button, which is correct (see image).

[image: Tooltip on non-touch screen]

However, on a pc with a touchscreen, the tooltip is showing to the right (when hovered over with the mouse). Even when the PC has 2 screens, one a touchscreen, the other a regular one, the tooltip is showing to the right on both screens.

Both PC's are running the same OS and .Net version.

When I change the Placement to "Right", the tooltip is showing on the right on a pc without touchscreen and to the left on a pc with a touchscreen.

Why the difference and what can I do so the tooltip is always shown on the left of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still don't know why it didn't work correctly with the original code, but I found a fix/workaround:

I've set Placement to Custom, and implemented the ToolTipOpening event handler. There I use the CustomPopupPlacementCallback delegate to set the position of the tooltip manually:

XAML:

```
            <ToggleButton Height="32" Width="32" ToolTipOpening="Button_OnToolTipOpening">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{someImage} />
                <ToggleButton.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Placement="Left" HorizontalOffset="-5">
                        <TextBlock Text="Search"/>
                    </ToolTip>
                </ToggleButton.ToolTip>
            </ToggleButton>
```

C#:

```
    private void Button_OnToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as ToggleButton;
        if (button == null) return;
        var toolTip = button.ToolTip as ToolTip;
        if (toolTip != null)
        {
            toolTip.PlacementTarget = button;
            toolTip.Placement = PlacementMode.Custom;
            toolTip.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = delegate
            {
                double offsetY = (button.Height - toolTip.ActualHeight) / 2;
                double offsetX = -toolTip.ActualWidth - 5;

                return new CustomPopupPlacement[] { new CustomPopupPlacement(new Point(offsetX, offsetY), PopupPrimaryAxis.Horizontal) };
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing may have been caused by your PC's touch settings, which are very well hidden. We had the exact same problem and changing them solved it for us (though it took us quite some time to find this...). Going with this solution means it has to be applied to every installation so it may not be practical in every case.

Change these settings by going to:

Control Panel --> Hardware and Sound --> Tablet PC settings.

Choose the "Other" tab and then change your settings from right-handed to left-handed or vice-versa.

For some versions of Windows 10 this path is no longer available the you can get there by pressing the Windows key + R to open the Run box. Type the following command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}
```

https://www.top-password.com/blog/fix-windows-10-opens-right-click-context-menu-to-left-side/

This setting is meant to keep the users from blocking the view of the pop-up with their fingers, I'm not sure why it tries to mess with cases where you actually specify placement.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this... i have just written important over there.... may work...

```
 <ToggleButton Height="32" Width="32">
            <Image Width="16" Height="16"Source="{someImage} />
            <ToggleButton.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Placement="Left !important" HorizontalOffset="-5">
                    <TextBlock Text="My Tooltip"/>
                </ToolTip>
            </ToggleButton.ToolTip>
        </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: I get a XAML parse exception on that !important. I think that's CSS syntax.

Comment: yes .... ok .... Right ....  may be this link can give you better idea to do [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.placement(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That's the property I'm using. I didn't found any documentation on MSDN on different behaviour of this property with touchscreens.

Comment: But u can set place of that image with help of this ..... Anyways i am seeking another answer ./.....

Comment: The problem is that the Placement-property behaves differently on a touchscreen than on another screen. On a (my) touchscreen it doesn't behave like documented on MSDN.